# Approximating integrals of continuous functions.

Tags: probability, integration, limits, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(E,d)$ be a complete and separable metric space. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $E$. Let $f \colon E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f \geq 0$. I want to find continuous and bounded functions $f_n \colon E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n \leq f$ such that 
$$
    \int_E f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
  = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_E f_n \,\mathrm{d}\mu.
$$
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_n=min(f,n)$  It looks straight forward.  It is along the lines of the elementary description of Lebesgue integral.