# are two metric equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Are this two metric equivalent in the space of probability measure?
$d_1(\mu, \nu) = sup | \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\nu- \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d \mu |$ where f is continuous and bounded function and next,
$d_2(\mu, \nu) = sup | \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\nu- \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d \mu |$ where f is Lipschitz function whose Lipschitz constant is bounded by $1$.

Comment: Yes: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/metrizability-of-weak-convergence-by-the-bounded-lipschitz-metric

Comment: Is f also has to be bounded by 1? In my definition, only lipschitz constant is bounded by 1. So may be something is missing.

Comment: You are right. Then it is not true due to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838628/weak-convergence-implies-convergence-on-continuous-functions

Comment: But what happen if there is no atom for measure that we are discussing?